# PyQT4 для Python 3.3

Tags: python, pyqt4

Добрый день! Подскажите, кто ставил PyQT4 для Python 3.3
Python поставил успешно, а вот с PyQT4 проблема:
скачал и x86, и x64, а при установке идет примерно до 25% а дальше пишет error writing to file <Имя файла>.dll
Причем имя файла всегда разное, то есть останавливается на разных файлах, а иногда они проходят. В чем дело и как мне все-таки установить PyQT4?

Comment: Я бы не рекомендовал использовать 3.3. Еще сыроват. Сам находил несколько багов.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [How to install PyQt4 on Windows using pip?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22640640/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Ставил, успешно. Проверьте целостность пакета PyQt, версию вашего пк и свободное место на диске (бывает и такое)

Comment: стоит упомянуть, что PyQt5 и PyQt4 нельзя одновременно поставить, используя [бинарные установщики](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download). В качестве альтернативы к PyQt4 [можно PySide поставить](http://wiki.qt.io/PySide_Binaries_Windows).